# What is a good away to compress AWS Lambda response to avoid 6MB limit?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, zip, aws-api-gateway

I have Lambda that performs several calls to DynamoDB, creates a big stringified JSON object as a response and passes to the client application via API Gateway. Naturally, API Gateway has "Content Encoding enabled" option set, and all data is passed over the internet in a compressed form.

The problem is that Lambda response itself is not compressed and it hits 6MB response limit. Is it possible to compress Lambda response and then decompress it on the client-side in some natural way?

I've checked node.js libraries like JSZip and ADM Zip and was surprised that despite they allow in-memory output for decompressed data they don't allow in-memory input like string, buffer or smth, only files. Lambda already has several restrictions and surprises related to working with files so I would like to avoid the following redundant workflow:

1. create JSON object
2. save it as a temporal file inside lambda environment
3. load the file via zipping library to compress and return to API Gateway

Is there any more natural way to deal with the issue?

Comment: you can hack the lib code a bit to accept strings as inputs instead of files

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've followed the next approach.
For backend:

```
const { deflate, unzip } = require("zlib");
const { promisify } = require("util");

const asyncDeflate = promisify(deflate);

async zip(object) {
    return (await asyncDeflate(JSON.stringify(object))).toString("base64");`
}
```

For front end:

```
import * as pako from "pako";

export function unzip(base64str: string) {
  const strData = atob(base64str);

  // Convert binary string to character-number array
  const charData = strData.split("").map((x) => { return x.charCodeAt(0); });

  // Turn number array into byte-array
  const binData = new Uint8Array(charData);

  return JSON.parse(pako.inflate(binData, { to: "string" }));
}
```

So it is rather similar to the recent answer.

Answer (score 11):

Although I agree that using pagination or S3 is more appropriate for large amounts of data, you can compress the response returned from your Lambda function in order to avoid hitting the 6MB limit if needed.

Unfortunately, although API Gateway now supports content encodings such as gzip, my understanding is that the Lambda function's response still needs to be below the 6MB limit prior to API Gateway compressing it. I am not 100% sure about this, so someone please correct me if I am wrong.

The good news is that the node.js standard library now has built-in support for gzip via the zlib module. I used this for compressing responses that were just barely above 6MB and reduced the sizes by about ~78%. The downside of this was that I had to decompress the data manually in my Angular client application (I used the pako npm library for this).

Something like below worked well for me (Typescript 4 + node.js 12):

```
import { APIGatewayEvent, APIGatewayProxyResult } from 'aws-lambda';
import { gzip } from 'zlib';

export const handler = async (event: APIGatewayEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
  const response = { some: 'data' };

  const gzippedResponse = await gzipString(JSON.stringify(response));

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({ data: gzippedResponse.toString('base64') }),
  };
};

const gzipString = async (input: string): Promise<Buffer> => {
  const buffer = Buffer.from(input);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => gzip(buffer, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
    resolve(data);
  }));
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Firstly, to clarify, API Gateway compression is not related to Lambda response compression at all - it's just saves your traffic. Secondly, I've followed similar approach, full details in my answer.

Comment: Right, my answer refers to compressing the Lambda response in order to avoid hitting the 6MB limitation imposed by API Gateway, which I think is what you were asking. It looks like we landed on similar solutions based on your other answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to handle this by slightly changing the architecture:

1. Return only a subset of the response using paging (this works best if the response contains a list of items that can be spilt into multiple pages).
2. Store part or all of the response in S3 (either prepared if the response is static or created on the fly if it’s dynamic) and return the object’s URL to the client for subsequent retrieval.

Comment: Hi Dennis, thank you for the reply. 1) This is the first expected option. However, DynamoDB doesn't support good pagination based on some clear criteria (like ElasticSearch does, for example - we plan to move to ES in the future). We already paginate in some way - the data which can hit Lambda limit is event data for one month. So even one month data hit the limit, but typically the user gets the data for 3 months at once (several calls are issued). 2) This approach looks as incredible overkill to me, since the calls are an ordinary workflow of the user.

Comment: Option 2 isn't much additional work on the caller side if the Lambda function returns an HTTP *303 See Other* response (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303) pointing to the object in S3.